# Is NFC required for reading RFID?

Tags: nfc

Can we read RFID like QR-bar code without NFC in Android? I am confused because we can read QR-Barcode with simple apps like [Bar Code Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android&hl=en). After searching 2-3 hours I found NFC with every detail where RFID is defined.

So I have to consider that it is impossible to read RFID without NFC.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can you read RFID without NFC? No you cannot.

Can you read QR-Code without a camera?

You need the right hardware to read codes. For reading QR-code you need an image of the QR-Code therefore a camera. Without a camera you cannot read QR-Code.

To read RFID you need hardware to read the code. The hardware needed is NFC, so without NFC you cannot read RFID.

Answer (score 1):

**RFID** states for Radio Frequency Identification, and this kind of technology use Radio Waves for identification purposes, now when we know RFID is nothing else than radio wave (electromagnetic field with specific frequency), we know we need transmitter (source of signal) and trans-coder (signal reading device) eg radio in your car and signal broadcasting antenna.

**NFC** - Near Field Communication is a specific kind of RFID technology and reading device can only read the signal from certain distance, all depends on the transmitter signal strenght and on the trans-coder operating field eg like a CB radio equipment, the bigger antenna you have the bigger operating field you got.